# Mailing API with formatting

Tags: c#, .net, api, email

i have a windows service which sends multiple e-mail alerts in several cases such as,

1. Operation performed successfully
2. Fatal Exceptions
3. Error in information validation
4. Maker Checker mechanism
5. Authorization
6. Pwd life cycle etc.

Right now I send these e-mails as plain text, so sometimes it can get difficult to read the e-mails. If i have to maintain html with placeholders for every type of email or use text templates there will be a lot of work.

Is there any API which could help me generalize these emails and provide a HTML depending upon the type of email?

Comment: i don't think so... i asked if there is an API which could generalize my problem and help me sending multiple type of emails and handle the HTML elements of email it self

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer, No

You will have to construct a simple handler for this and it wouldn't take much effort.